# Posting items to RDS db table using AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-sdk

I wanted to use RDS to store data created within my webapp.

I am already storing data in dynamo tables and can pipe the same data into S3 files.
Due to some project requirements, I wanted to store the data into RDS tables. I havent found any resources to help me find a way to use the AWS Java SDK to store data incrementally into RDS.

Does any one know of a way to do that? Or is there any way to achieve that via some other way?

Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging up myself and Anthony helping me out with clarification, I understand it better.

In case anyone else comes here searching for the same issue:

The endpoint that is provided for the database you create in RDS can be used to write into the table or execute any db query, for that matter.

Here is a nice tutorial to get you started.

http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqljavatutorial/

Good luck guys.

Comment: Link not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the AWS SDK to store data in Amazon RDS like Dynamo DB.  RDS is a managed database service that hosts many different database engines (Amazon Aurora, MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle, SQL Server, and PostgreSQL database engines) that each have their own clients and protocols for transferring data.

You'll need to evaluate these database engines separately, determine which one you want to use, and use a client for that engine to read and write your data.

The AWS SDK and APIs can be used to provision and modify your RDS DB instances (the servers hosting your database) but not to manipulate or read the data itself.  You can view the [API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) for a full listing of available actions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification :)

Comment: This was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just came accross this post. My understanding is that you don't need AWS SDK:

- you make the databse accessible from the Internet
- you use traditional jdbc calls as with any other db

This info is in the manual of the management console, but it is valid in general:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html